# Regex to validate password containing a digit rejects string with multiple digits

Tags: regex, validation

I have the following pattern to validate a password form (not ideal, I know, but it’s for an assignment).

```
/^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,})(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

My idea is, I need the password to be at least 8 letters long, and include at least one number and one letter. It also cannot include any special characters.

It accepts `password1` as a password, but it does not accept `password12` as a password. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/) may help you.

Comment: Why do you need the `(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z]*$)`? It means that the whole password must contain exactly one digit between any number of letters from start to finish.

Comment: Try `^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$`

Comment: Thanks for the link ctwheels, i'm aware of this but it's for a bit of coursework where the submission needs to include a password that is only 8 letters, include 1 digit and 1 letter but no special characters. I'm not sure Xufox, i'll remove it and test.

Comment: @JohnDoi2021 Don’t just remove it. Try this here: `/^(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$/`.

Comment: that works ctwheels, i can accept your answer if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is close but has some issues:

The portion `(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z]*$)` means *“assert that **exactly one** digit (`[0-9]`) exists from start to finish (`$`) with any number of letters around it (2× `[a-zA-Z]*`)”*.

Instead, you want something like this:

```
/^(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$/
```

Here, `(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])` and `(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z])` mean *“assert that a digit exists after any number of letters”* and *“assert that a letter exists after any number of digits”* respectively.

After that, you can simply match `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}`.